# Taking a Full Size Photo with Camera Intent and Saving It

Tags: android, image, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am following this Android Developer's tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I used the exact codes in this tutorial. However, It returns null while creating the image file in `createImageFile()` function.

Could you please look at my code and tell me what I'm missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView mImageView;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    Button takepicturebtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        takepicturebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takepicturebtn);

        takepicturebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });


    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath ="file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setPic();
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setPic() {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

}
```

And here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.figengungor.takingcamerapicture" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new on this site, but I have already had same problem. What I did:
In Manifest I used such code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Since I didn't use landscape orientation for my app, each time when I push button save the picture from camera new MainActivity is being created and method OnCreated is calling again. But created file left in previous one.
As for Inten data - it is still null, so I put in ImageView my file (change size before). Instead of using method setPic(), I use this code (do not forget to initialize File photoFile in class):

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
 imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 // Resize the bitmap to 150x100 (width x height)
 Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 100, true);
 // Loads the resized Bitmap into an ImageView
 imageView.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
```

or
You can use method setPic(), but you need to change everywhere in this method mCurrentPhotoPath to photoFile.getAbsolutePath(). It works.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the exact codes in this tutorial

Actually, you combined things where you were supposed to choose one or the other.

[The Save the Full-Size Photo section](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) has you *either* use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` *or* use `getExternalFilesDir()`. You chose the former, which is fine. However, you *also* added the `android:maxSdkVersion` to the `<uses-permission>` element, which is part of the instructions for using `getExternalFilesDir()`. You need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on all relevant versions of Android to work with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

You have three choices:

1. Remove `android:maxSdkVersion`. Then, make sure that your `targetSdkVersion` (in `app/build.gradle`, assuming you have a traditional Android Studio project) is 22 or lower, or that you are testing on Android 5.1 or lower.
2. Remove `android:maxSdkVersion`, while leaving `targetSdkVersion` at 23 (or higher) and testing on Android 6.0 (or higher). In that case, you also have to deal with the fact that `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a `dangerous` permission on Android 6.0+ and needs to be handled through the runtime permission system.
3. Switch to using `getExternalFilesDir()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Comment: My targetSdkVersion is 23. I removed android:maxExternalStorage from the permission.  Now my onActivityResult is not triggered even though when I put some breakpoints in it and tried to debug it.(Option 2 didn't work)

Comment: I also tried to switch to getExternalFilesDir(). However, this time it creates the file but when it comes to setPic() step,  bmOptions.outWidth and bmOptions.outHeight returns 0 after decoding mCurrentPhotoPath and that leads to divide by zero exception when it comes to scaleFactor step.

Comment: @FigenGüngör: "I removed android:maxExternalStorage from the permission" -- sorry, I meant `android:maxSdkVersion`. "Now my onActivityResult is not triggered..." -- presumably, you are not requesting the permissions at runtime (see item #2). "bmOptions.outWidth and bmOptions.outHeight returns 0 after decoding mCurrentPhotoPath" -- perhaps the image is not being stored there. The docs do not mention that many camera apps are buggy and may not necessarily write the image to the designated location.

Comment: @FigenGüngör: Their code has other bugs (`mCurrentPhotoPath` is neither a path, nor a valid `Uri`, but something else that may not be recognized by the camera app and certainly will not be recognized by `BitmapFactory`).

Comment: Oh I meant android:maxSdkVersion in first place, sorry about that. And btw I am testing the app on a device which version is lower than 23 so do I still have to write those runtime permissions? I thought I'll add  those permission later for >=23.

Comment: Here it says that if I target 23 but use lower than 23 device, it'll use the old permission model: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions#references

Comment: @FigenGüngör: "do I still have to write those runtime permissions?" -- no, but that will be needed once you start using Android 6.0.